# Excel Sum Based on Several Criteria

Tags: excel

```
   A         B       C            

1  10/1/2009 3652449 12:15:43 AM
2  10/1/2009 3652449 12:17:03 AM
3  10/4/2009 3652449 1:03:08 AM
```

Hello,

I want to sum the total time of the card 3652449 just for 10/1/2009.

Then after the sum is compete I need the time to be converted and rounded into minutes only.

I have been using the following formula till now  " =SUMIF(B:B,3652449,C:C) " and the result is " 1:35:54 ". But as I have written I want to sum the time for that card only on the date of 10/1/2009. When you copy the data in excel and you manually sum the time from 10/1/2009 you should get 32m & 46s. When you round it the result should be 32m.

I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: Your example data is too confusing. How would you calculate the total time? Is one a start time and one an end time?

Comment: @Trollkid: You can edit your question (use the `edit` link) to format your data (`Code Sample` button can help you) and to provide more information about when and how to sum your data.

Comment: @Trollkid: Thanks for editing, but it is still not clear what you want to sum and how. Could you please separate clearly what data you have and what the result would look like?

Comment: Sorry my example was too confusing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pivot table, which can easily give you the sum for every date in your table.

Pivot tables are supported in all good desktop spreadsheets, but not many online web-based ones.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table

Comment: +1, now I understand the requirements, pivot table is definitely the way to go (and you can do it with Excel).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if I got you right.

If you want to add the date as condition, you can try something like that:

Add a formula to your column D: `=B1&" "&A1`

This should give you the following result:

```
   A         B       C            D
1  10/1/2009 3652449 12:15:43 AM  3652449 40087
2  10/1/2009 3652449 12:17:03 AM  3652449 40087
3  10/4/2009 3652449 1:03:08 AM   3652449 40090
```

Now you can change your original formula to: `=SUMIF(D:D,"3652449 40087",C:C)`

You can make column D invisible by either changing width to 0 or changing color to white.

Hope that is what you tried...

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, but the problem is that I sometimes have around 10 000 rows. I can not edit all the rows to add the formula. =SUMIF(D:D,"3652449 40087",C:C). You know there are different cards and the date is constantly changing.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why do you write the `SUMIF` in everery row? Shouldn't it be sufficient to write it once and change it there?

Comment: There are 50 cards and 31 days of the month and having in mind that the rows can get up to 10 000. Sure I can copy paste the formula, but then I have to change the "3652449 40087" or "3652449 40090" or any other as the card or date changes. I need for every single card a sum of the time for every day of the month.